# Create output for file based on patterns in the input lines

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have a file listing, with many lines like this:

```
./file_name_0.jpg
./file_name_1.jpg
./file_name_2.jpg
./file_name_3.jpg
./file_name_4.jpg
./file_name_5.jpg
./file_name.jpg
./file_name1_0.jpg
./file_name1_1.jpg
./file_name1.jpg
./file_name2_0.jpg
./file_name2_1.jpg
./file_name2_2.jpg
./file_name2_3.jpg
./file_name2_4.jpg
./file_name2_5.jpg
./file_name2.jpg
```

In the listing above I have two files which I know to have been duplicated exactly 6 times. I want to have these duplicates removed. Where the file has been copied less than 6 times, I want to have the file remain.

In other words, what I would like to achieve is to remove all files where the filenames have ALL of the variations `_0.jpg`, `_1.jpg`,`_2.jpg`,`_3.jpg`,`_4.jpg`,`_5.jpg` at the end.

For the above input, I would like something like this as output

```
rm ./file_name_0.jpg
rm ./file_name_1.jpg
rm ./file_name_2.jpg
rm ./file_name_3.jpg
rm ./file_name_4.jpg
rm ./file_name_5.jpg
# ./file_name.jpg    # do not remove, it is the original file.
# ./file_name1_0.jpg # do not remove, it is a legitimate copy.
# ./file_name1_1.jpg # do not remove, it is a legitimate copy.
# ./file_name1.jpg   # do not remove, it is the original file.
rm ./file_name2_0.jpg
rm ./file_name2_1.jpg
rm ./file_name2_2.jpg
rm ./file_name2_3.jpg
rm ./file_name2_4.jpg
rm ./file_name2_5.jpg
# ./file_name2.jpg
```

The difficulty I'm having is making sure files like `file_name1_1.jpg` are not removed - this is a legitimate file because there are less than 6 duplicates in that set.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you mean. Why don't you `rm ./filename1_1.jpg` and instead `# ./filename1_1.jpg`?

Comment: OP wants to delete the whole set of filenamen_* if all six files from 0-5 exist.

Comment: Yes if and only if I have all six from _0.jpg, _1.jpg, _2.jpg right through to _5.jpg. Only then do I want to delete them.

Comment: -1. Please edit your question and make it clear. I'm usually pretty tolerant to screwed English and messed up conditions, but your "I would like to got through the file", "when all 5 of the above variations" given 6 patterns above, and, finally, specifying your problem with `*` patterns (which match *anything*, when you mean that this part should be equal among 6 files) is beyond my patience.

Comment: @GreyCat Fair comment. I've edited the question.

Comment: @mcaleaa: Thanks, I've made an upvote now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an executable awk script which will indicate the desired files to "rm":

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {FS="_"}

{ sub(FS $NF "$", ""); key=$0 } # make a key by dropping the last field

{ cnts[key]++ }         # count how many matching prefixes there are

END {
  for(key in cnts) {            # for a count `key` in cnts
    if(cnts[key]==6) {          # check to see if the `key` cnt is 6
      for(i=0;i<6;i++) {        # if it is build an output line for each case
        print "rm " key FS i ".jpg"   # make the output `command` here.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This doesn't show lines that were preserved.  It only creates an `rm` command for each file that should be removed.  Also note that it assumes every file ends with ".jpg".  The order of the output is not guaranteed, but can be piped through `sort` if you need it ordered.  This should also work in cases where a `_` appears in the filename.

From your input, it yields:

```
rm ./filename2_0.jpg
rm ./filename2_1.jpg
rm ./filename2_2.jpg
rm ./filename2_3.jpg
rm ./filename2_4.jpg
rm ./filename2_5.jpg
rm ./filename_0.jpg
rm ./filename_1.jpg
rm ./filename_2.jpg
rm ./filename_3.jpg
rm ./filename_4.jpg
rm ./filename_5.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to edit the FS so that it only matches the last instance of underscore "_". Some of the file_names have underscores in them.

Comment: In this case, since the data isn't really being preserved, I'd advocate just making a different key for `cnts`.  I'm doing this by blanking the last field out of `$0`.

Answer (score 0):

This does not *exactly* solve your problem, in that it does not actually make sure that files 0-5 are there.  Instead it just checks that there are 6 suffixed files there:

```
grep _ temp.txt | cut -d_ -f1 | sort | uniq -c | \
 grep '^ *6' | sed -e 's/^ *6 /rm /' -e 's/$/_*.jpg/'
```

First it isolates lines with underscore characters, then it gets just the part before the first underscore, then it sorts everything, then it counts the number of occurrences of each prefix, then it grabs just the prefixes that occur 6 times, then it replaces the count with an `rm` and adds a glob back onto the end to match all the files with that prefix.